# Standard URN for country codes?

Tags: urn

I wonder if there are some common URNs for ISO 3166 2-/3-letter country codes?

All I found was URNs for the standard itself as part of some health care [project](http://hl7.org/fhir/2018May/iso3166.html) and [LinkedIn's vendor-specific URNs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/standardized-data/locations/regions#) (like `"urn:li:country:us"`).

I suspect that there should be no need to invent the wheel, but can't find anything more or less standard. Maybe, there is even some kind of meta-standard for this very few are aware about.

In this case it's not about interoperability yet, but to make an intelligent choice between ad hoc and something in much wider use.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean this :

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/urns

i dont not understand what you trying to ask.
because `urn:li:country` will allways stay the same all you have to edit is the `us` part.

Comment: Sure, but "li" is for LinkedIn there - it's vendor-specific way to build country URN. I am asking if there is some standard way, something like `urn:iso:std:iso:3166:country:us` , but used by more than one vendor.

Comment: my bad i didnt understand the question yes there is a standard, but it requires lookup work. the problem mostly is the entity type in this case it is `country`. every URN will use different enities. linkedin has a predifend list of those they use. but the list is poorly managed because country isnt even on that list.  
  
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/urn-namespace